# How to properly chain actions in Flux (alt)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, alt

I'm working on React project and we are using Alt library for handling actions and stores. I can not find an answer to how is it possible to chain two actions without resorting to setTimeout() or otherwise hacking the Flux paradigm.

My understanding is that an event is happening in a React component, which triggers an Action, which cascades down to Stores. Stores are not allowed to initiate any new actions or modify data in other stores. But sometimes we need to chain several actions in a sequence. Is it possible to spawn two actions, and one would listen to when the other one is completed?

Consider an example.
A group of people is standing next to a car. An event is prompting them to get into the car and start driving. In a world of Flux, it can be seen as two actions "Get in" and "Go". Each of the persons (think of them as "stores") is independent and may take variable time to get seated. The driver needs to make sure that everybody is seated before proceeding to the next action - "Go". And "Go" is not something that can be confined to the driver - it can take effects (like motion sickness) on other passengers.

How can this be implemented in Flux (Alt)?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, an action can trigger several actions. Observable & Promise are very usefull to chain several action dispatchings. If you want to try observable, take a look a [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS). And for promise, I used [blue bird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

If you use Redux, take a look at [Redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) that actually provide an alternative to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe [action.defer](http://alt.js.org/docs/actions/) is what you need.

```
CarActions.getIn(driver,passengers)
CarActions.go.defer(driver)
```